# Misconception on inner product form with bilinearity

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T$ be a unitary operator on a finite dimensional space $V$, then one can say that for all $v \in V$, we have $$\langle T(v),T(v) \rangle = \langle v , v \rangle$$

Naively, i did some rearranging of terms in the following manner which now i realized is wrong: $$\langle T(v),T(v) \rangle - \langle v , v \rangle = 0 \implies \langle T(v)-v,T(v) - v \rangle = \langle 0, 0 \rangle$$

This is a wrong step because bilinearity does not guarantee linearity when both sides have no element in common at their respective places.

i.e If $\langle T(v) ,T(v) \rangle = \langle v,T(v) \rangle$ then i can deduce that $$\langle T(v) - v , T(v) \rangle = \langle 0, 0 \rangle$$

My question is, was my original step on the "linearity" wrong? I just need someone to confirm this so i can stop using this idea. Thanks! Also this was the proof to prove that $T$ is normal and unitary implies eigenvalues are all absolute $1$ in case you are wondering.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Edited, thanks!

Comment: You've learned that you cannot conclude $\langle T(v)-v,T(v)-v\rangle=0$ from when $T$ is unitary.... hhhmmm sorry what is $\langle 0,0\rangle$?

Comment: Oh $\langle 0,0 \rangle$ is just $0$, maybe i should make it clearer

Comment: Is $V$ a finite dimensional space?  If not, then you'll have to clarify what you mean by eigenvalue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your original step is wrong. Notably, we have
$$
\langle Tv - v ,Tv-v\rangle  = 
\langle Tv,Tv \rangle - \langle Tv,v \rangle - \langle v, Tv \rangle + \langle v,v \rangle
$$
by "FOILing". In any case, here's a push in the right direction.

**Hint:** Suppose that $v$ is and eigenvector of $T$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, and "plug $v$ in" to the equation
$$
\langle T(v),T(v) \rangle = \langle v,v \rangle
$$
what can we say about $\lambda$?

Comment: Oh, you mean i can make it to: $\langle \lambda v, \lambda v \rangle = \langle v, v \rangle$ implying that we can take out the $\lambda$ by linearity and have $\lambda \overline{\lambda} \langle v,v\rangle = \langle v,v\rangle$ forcing $\lambda \overline{\lambda} = 1$

Comment: @ilovewt exactly, keeping in mind that $v \neq 0$ by the definition of an eigenvector.

Comment: i see, thank you, so i cannot blindly apply bilinearity onto inner product like i did previously. I must check they must have a common element. @Omnomnomnom

Comment: And also, why is the condition $T$ being normal there. Is it for us to prove the converse? @Omnomnomnom

Comment: @ilovewt honestly, I'm not really sure.  Any unitary transformation is automatically normal.